# Laravel Migrations are migrating successfully but they are not creating foreign key relationship in tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-relations

My Laravel App is creating all tables in migrations successfully but it's failing to create a foreign keys relationships in the table or even enforce cascade when I delete the primary record.
Here is the migration.

```
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('excerpt');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

When I run  `php artisan migrate` it's migrating successfully.

```
λ php artisan migrate

Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.11 seconds)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (0.1 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (0.07 seconds)
Migrating: 2020_08_26_122846_create_articles_table
Migrated:  2020_08_26_122846_create_articles_table (0.14 seconds)
```

But, when I check the database, the relationship is not getting created, just and index for foreign key.
[Check the Articles Table image in this link. I have marked the necessary parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHKJj.png)

[Check the Users Table image here. I have highlighted the primary key.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pgpl.png)

I have added some factory data relating the user and article and when I delete the user, the articles are being left as orphans.

What could be wrong?

- PHP Version: 7.3.21
- MySql Version: 5.7.31
- MariaDB Version: 10.4.13
- Laravel Framework Version: 7.25.0

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: Are your tables using the InnoDB engine?

Comment: Wow! No, that feature was null and have added it then it has worked like magic. Thankyou!

Comment: @ShakilAhmmed, would you mind adding it as an answer so that I can mark it? So that it can help others in future?

Comment: Sure, I already adding it as answer.

Comment: @ShakilAhmmed no you haven't I will add it anyway..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been answered in the comment by @ShakilAhmmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63617385/laravel-migrations-are-migrating-successfully-but-they-are-not-creating-foreign?noredirect=1#comment112500962_63617385)

All I did was go to `config` folder then `database.php` and change mysql database engine from null to innoDB
i.e.
From:

```
//...
'engine' => null,
//...
```

To:

```
//...
'engine' => 'InnoDB',
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Schema::create` for creating the tables.

In the Laravel docs, I see `Schema::table` when working with foreign keys. Perhaps you should try to split your code:

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('excerpt');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

});
```