# PHP Laravel migration file does not create relation

Tags: php, laravel, database, migration, database-migration

I want to create a relation between the users-table and my other tabe in php laravel. After migrating this with the command:

- `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

nothing happens

The migration file:

```
$table
    ->unsignedBigInteger('updated_from')
    ->nullable()
    ->foreign('updated_from')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('users');
```

And after refreshing the erd in datagrip there is no relation between the two tables:
[image]

There is no relation. The other arrow comes from another table.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63617385/laravel-migrations-are-migrating-successfully-but-they-are-not-creating-foreign, and by the way, you can use `-> foreignId('update_from')` as helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with explicit foreign key:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('updated_from')->nullable();
$table->foreign('updated_from')->references('id')->on('users');
```